# Print lists in a dictionary based on the status of change/depchanges

Tags: python

Following is what I am trying, not sure where I'm messing up. I have the expected output at the bottom. Can anyone provide input on what is wrong here?

1. Create a lists in a dictionary for each master change and its dependent change
2. Repeat step #1 until the depchange status is not NEW

My code:

```
def depchange(change):
    depchange_status=''
    if change == "23456":
        depchange=33456
        depchange_status == 'NEW'
    if change == "33456":
        depchange=""
        depchange_status == 'COMPLETED'
    return (depchange,depchange_status)


def main ():
    master_change="23456"
    dep={}
    while True:
        dep_change,depchange_status=depchange(master_change)
        master_change = dep_change
        dep[master_change]=dep_change
        if depchange_status != 'NEW':
            break
    print dep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


'''
EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
dep = {
    '23456': ['33456'],
    '33456': [],
    }
'''
```

Comment: Have some more `readable` code, don't differ the variablenames by just 1 underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, in your depchange() function, do you actually mean to *compare* the depchange_status, or do you mean to change them? You had '==' there.

There's that, and in that same function, depchange is switched from a string to an int. I assume you wanted it to stay a string.

```
def depchange(change):
    depchange_status=''
    if change == "23456":
        depchange="33456"
        depchange_status = 'NEW'
    if change == "33456":
        depchange=""
        depchange_status = 'COMPLETED'
    return (depchange,depchange_status)


def main ():
    master_change="23456"
    dep={}
    while True:
        dep_change,depchange_status=depchange(master_change)
        dep[master_change]=[dep_change]
        master_change = dep_change
        if depchange_status != 'NEW':
            break
    print dep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @Trueerror - I see the values are not printed as list ..currently they are printed as {'33456': '', '23456': '33456'}..how to make the values as list?

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of these two lines. You want to use the old value of `master_change` in the assignment to `dep`.

```
master_change = dep_change
dep[master_change]=dep_change
```

Also you have `==` instead of `=` in a couple of assignments.

```
depchange_status == 'NEW'
depchange_status == 'COMPLETED'
```

Comment: that fixed part of my problem but the while loop doesnt seem to be working.. i still dont see "'33456': []," getting printed...33456 is a dependent change with status "NEW"... further 33456 doesnt have any dependecies,so while loop should stop here